# Converting integer to char for each number?

Tags: c, arrays, parsing, char, int

I have a display hooked up to a processor which I'm programming. It is part of a weather station and I need to display temperature and other data.

There is however one problem. Writing Integers to the display is not possible, because the display's own controller uses a databus of 8 bits to determine which character will be written.

Note that the function `DisplayPrint` I've written takes an array of chars. The array is then analysed and a ';' character determines where the array stops. I would do
`DisplayPrint("Temperature: ;")`  in order to write "Temperature: " on the display.

Here is the question: **how can I send an integer and return an array of chars?**

Example:
Function is called `parseChar`

```
int x = 100;  
char string[255];  
string = parseChar(x);
```

`x` goes into `parseChar`, `parseChar` returns an array that looks like;

```
string[0] = '1'  
string[1] = '0'  
string[2] = '0'  
string[3] = ';'  
string[4 to 254] = *don't care, can be anything*
```

I have been sitting two days on this with little to no success at all.

---

This is not programming for pc.

I'm using J-tag hooked up to a Arduino DUE which is hooked up to a Display with controller. Programming is done with **IAR Embedded Workbench**

Comment: @HotLicks: And you're using that in C?

Comment: Stuff looked like Java there for a second.  But no biggie in C either -- I'd just have to look up the interface or (simple enough) code my own int to string routine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the string to your number + semicolon:

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d;", x);
```

Comment: Okaay... snprintf(the char array, number of places, format, the things to format...) ?

Does this function return anything or does it only affect the buffer?
What do I need to include to use strlen?

Comment: It returns the number of characters written (not including the trailing `0`). You don't need `strlen()` anymore since you updated the question to not require filling the rest of the buffer; if you *did* want to use it elsewhere, `#include <string.h>`.

Comment: I haven't programmed a lot in C so there is one more thing I would like to ask about.

When declaring an array of chars, is every char in the array set to the NULL char?

Comment: No (or, not usually). The array contents will be uninitialized; don't expect any particular value. Use `memset()` if you want to assure nulls. The exception: `static` variables are initialized to `0`, but that only happens once; if you use a static variable within a function, it won't necessarily be `0` on the 2nd and subsequent call to the function.

Comment: Alright, thanks a lot. You really saved me from a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using parseChar, you might use snprinf.

```
snprintf(string, sizeof(string), "%d;", x);
```

And if you would like the rest of the buffer to be `0`s, just clear it before hand with memset.

```
memset(string, 0, sizeof(string));
```

Comment: Note that, for some reason, the OP wants the rest of the buffer filled with '0' chars.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `snprintf` (http://linux.die.net/man/3/snprintf) as indicated in other answers.

However, if you want to know the logic behind converting a decimal to a string, you should consider using mod operations on 10. Example:

First)

```
2345 % 10 = 5
2345/10 = 234 (integer)
```

Then)

```
234 % 10 = 4
234 / 10 = 23
```

Then)

```
23 % 10 = 3
23 / 10 = 2
```

Then)

```
2 % 10 = 2
2 / 10 = 0 (stop)
```

Therefore, you just need a while loop that will stop when the division is 0. To convert the int digits to chars you just need `str[i] = 2 + '0';`, for example (more on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1114741/how-to-convert-int-to-char-c).